# Web scraping with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

I'm trying to fill and submit form with Capybara. I have a code that looks like this:

```
session = Capybara::Session.new(:webkit)
session.visit "https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=4&ct=1463412429&rver=6.1.6206.0&wp=MCMBI&wreply=https:%2F%2Fwebpooldb41e06.infra.lync.com%2FPassiveAuth%2FPassiveAuth.aspx%3FredirectUrl%3Dhttps%253a%252f%252fwebpooldb41e06.infra.lync.com%252fScheduler%252f&lc=1033&id=266537"
session.fill_in('cred_userid_inputtext', :with => 'my@email.com')
session.fill_in('cred_password_inputtext', :with => '12341234')
session.save_page
```

When I save this page to the file and open it I see that form wasn't filled and submitted...

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you `save_screenshot` instead?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't calling submit anywhere in that code.  You are simply filling in field values and then calling save page.  You need to add a `trigger('click')` method after you fill in the form to submit it.  You should then call the `current_url` method on your session after that to see if it made it to the next page in your console.  In ruby it would simply be:

```
puts session.current_url
```

And if all is correct you would see the new url to the page after form submission in your console.

Answer (score 1):

`#save_page` saves the html of the page, it doesn't save updated element properties which get updated when you fill in text fields. `#save_screenshot` should show the fields filled in though.